# Why isn't andalso/2 implemented as a proper BIF?

Tags: erlang

I'm able to write prefix boolean expressions like `erlang:'and'(true, false)`, but not the corresponding `andalso` or `orelse` expressions. Why?

When I look at the core output, it looks like `andalso` and `orelse` are just macros - for example:

```
a(A,B) -> A and B.
```

translates to the core

```
'a'/2 =
    %% Line 4
    fun (_cor1,_cor0) ->
        call 'erlang':'and'
            (_cor1, _cor0)
```

but andalso goes from

```
b(A,B) -> A andalso B.
```

to

```
'b'/2 =
    %% Line 6
    fun (_cor1,_cor0) ->
        ( case _cor1 of
            ( <( 'true'
                 -| ['compiler_generated'] )> when 'true' ->
                  _cor0
              -| ['compiler_generated'] )
            ( <( 'false'
                 -| ['compiler_generated'] )> when 'true' ->
                  'false'
              -| ['compiler_generated'] )
            ( <_cor2> when 'true' ->
                  ( call ( 'erlang'
                           -| ['compiler_generated'] ):( 'error'
                                                         -| ['compiler_generated'] )
                        (( {( 'badarg'
                              -| ['compiler_generated'] ),_cor2}
                           -| ['compiler_generated'] ))
                    -| ['compiler_generated'] )
              -| ['compiler_generated'] )
          end
          -| ['compiler_generated'] )
```

It looks like it's implemented this way to preserve laziness, but it wouldn't have to be in this step -- e.g. there could still be a `call 'erlang':'andalso'` line, which is translated later.

Is it just an oversight that `erlang:'andalso'(A,B)` isn't equivalent to `A andalso B`, or does some kind of "premature expansion" make that difficult?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main reason is that calls to BIFs behave in the same way as calls to "normal" functions in that they are strict in their arguments, **all** the arguments are evaluated before the BIF/function is called. The distinguishing thing with `andalso` and `orelse` is that they **don't** evaluate all their arguments but only the first argument. Then depending on what value of the first argument they may or may not evaluate the second. This means that even if they were BIFS they would have to be specially treated by the compiler anyway so there is very little point in making them BIFs.

Also the expansion is very straightforward so there would be little gain in doing as a they specially handled BIF.

Comment: Still, couldn't the user be allowed to write e.g. `erlang:'andalso'(true, false)`, which would be disassembled into the laziness-preserving case expression?

Comment: @amindfv `and`, `or`, `andalso` and `orelse` are intended for using in infix form. `erlang:'and'/2` and `erlang:'or'/2` are implemented as BIFs because there have to be implemented somewhere. `andalso` and `orelse` are implemented as expansion in compiler because they have to be implemented in this way to work properly but `erlang:'andalso'/2` and `erlang:'orelse'/2` doesn't have to be implemented anywhere so they doesn't. Get rid of surplus (waste) is Erlang spirit.

Comment: @amindfv Yes, if you had the BIF calls `erlang:'andalso'/2` and `erlang:''orelse/2` then the compiler would have to special case them and expand them to much the same code as you get today. So, yes, KISS rules.

Comment: Too bad; I'm not a fan of infix non-operators

Comment: @amindfv They are infix operators, they are just implemented in Erlang and not in C. And as I have tried to show they are easy to implement in Erlang and much more difficult to implement in C.

Comment: By "operators" I meant functions named with symbols. That may only be a Haskell use of the word, though